# Works in Debugger mode but not in final release....WHY?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

...iam new here and i have a problem that my code logic seems error free (and it does) and when i run it in debugger mode (using microsoft visual express C++) everything work as it should  by monitoring the variables and its changes however when i run it in release mode its strange that nothing work...or change

what iam trying to do is moving a sprite in a black window (800x600) increasing its X co-ordinate by 1 till it reaches the end of the screen which is (spriteX +24 >798) (24 is the width of the bounding box of the sprite) then when that happens it moves to the other end of the screen then it stops....

the sprite spawn randomly at any point in screen then it moves to right then to left then stops and that what happens in debugger mode ... but in release mode it always spawn in the left edge of screen and not even move to the right or left it just stay there......

here is the code of the sprite moving

```
   void Game::PooMove()
{
    /*for (int index = 0; index < npoo; index++)*/
    bool iamfree = true;
    bool iamfree2 = false;
    while (iamfree)
    {
        poox[1]++;

        if (poox[1] + 24 > 799)
        {
            iamfree = false;
            iamfree2 = true;
        }
    }
    while (iamfree2)
    {
        poox[1]--;
        if (poox[1] < 1)
        {
            iamfree2 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and thats the code for random spawn of the sprite

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int index = 0; index < npoo; index++)
    {
        poox[index] = rand() % (800 - 24);
        pooy[index] = rand() % (600 - 24);
        pooIsEaten[index] = false;
    }
```

considering that its part of a bigger program everything works fine but my problem is in those condition that don't work expect in the debugger only and iam curious to know the solution and why this happens 
*i can upload the full code/file if that will make things clearer *

here is the drawing code and its calling

```
void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < npoo; index++)
    {
        if (!(pooIsEaten[index]))
        Drawpoo(poox[index], pooy[index]);
    }
}
void Game::Go()
{   
    UpDateFace();
    UpDatePoo();
    UpDateDot();
    gfx.BeginFrame();
    ComposeFrame();
    PooMove();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}
```

go function is what calls everything and some are being called in some specific functions like compose frame

thats how drawpoo function work hope the post don't get shut down due to this code

```
void Game::Drawpoo(int x,int y)
{
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 0 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 1 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 1 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 1 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 2 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 2 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 2 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 3 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 4 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 4 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 4 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 5 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 5 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 5 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 6 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 6 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 7 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 7 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 7 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 7 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 8 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 8 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 8 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 9 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 9 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 9 + y, 102, 57, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 9 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 9 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 9 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 9 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 10 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 10 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 10 + y, 102, 57, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 10 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 10 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 10 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 10 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 11 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 11 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 11 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 11 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 11 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 11 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 11 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 11 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 12 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 12 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 12 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 12 + y, 111, 62, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 12 + y, 102, 57, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 12 + y, 102, 57, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 12 + y, 102, 57, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 12 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 13 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 13 + y, 109, 61, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 13 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 13 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 13 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 13 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 13 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 13 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 14 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 14 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 14 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 14 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 14 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 14 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 14 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 14 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 14 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 14 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 14 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 15 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 15 + y, 116, 65, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 15 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 15 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 15 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 15 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 16 + y, 116, 65, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 16 + y, 109, 61, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 16 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 16 + y, 123, 69, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(19 + x, 16 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(0 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 17 + y, 87, 49, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 17 + y, 87, 49, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 17 + y, 87, 49, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 17 + y, 87, 49, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 17 + y, 43, 24, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 17 + y, 40, 22, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 17 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 17 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 17 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 17 + y, 123, 69, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(19 + x, 17 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(0 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 18 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 18 + y, 123, 69, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(19 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(22 + x, 18 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(0 + x, 19 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 19 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 19 + y, 123, 69, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(19 + x, 19 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 19 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(22 + x, 19 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(23 + x, 19 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 20 + y, 123, 69, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(19 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 20 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(22 + x, 20 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(23 + x, 20 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(0 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 21 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 21 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 21 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 21 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 21 + y, 138, 77, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(8 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(9 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(10 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(11 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(12 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(15 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(16 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(17 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(18 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(20 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(21 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(22 + x, 21 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(0 + x, 22 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 22 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 22 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 22 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 22 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 22 + y, 65, 36, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 22 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(1 + x, 23 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(2 + x, 23 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(3 + x, 23 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(4 + x, 23 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(5 + x, 23 + y, 51, 28, 0);
    gfx.PutPixel(6 + x, 23 + y, 51, 28, 0);
}
```

and how poox and pooy are declared

```
#define NPOO 3
class Game{
/*many functions and variables*/
int poox[NPOO];
int pooy[NPOO];
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you're doing any drawing operation inside your loop which does the move. How is it supposed to move if you don't redraw it?

Comment: are you sure that anything is actually wrong. I suspect that when you say "by monitoring the variables" you mean "setting a breakpoint and stepping through". In release mode you cannot reliably use breakpoints and stepping through only really makes sense in the disassembly when you have optimizations enabled

Comment: @DarkFalcon the drawing is by putpixel calls (manual drawing) hope that clarify it to you

Comment: @PeterT yes i exactly do this,
what else can i do to ensure that it works?

Comment: @Eyad: Sure, but if you want to see it move, you have to redraw it every time you change the x coordinate, and I don;t see your code doing that.

Comment: @DarkFalcon thats how its drawn and ofc i can't paste the full code cause the drawing is so long but you will get the idea
void Game::Drawpoo(int x,int y)
{
 gfx.PutPixel(14 + x, 0 + y, 138, 77, 0);
 gfx.PutPixel(7 + x, 1 + y, 138, 77, 0);
 gfx.PutPixel(13 + x, 1 + y, 138, 77, 0);
}
and so on

Comment: sorry dont know how to view it in code form in comments

Comment: But you don't call `Drawpoo` from `PooMove`. That means it might be happily incrementing and decrementing the x but you don;t see a thing because *you never redraw it while x is changing*

Comment: @DarkFalcon supposing that what you are saying is the problem i tested it before adding the second condition (iamfree2) and it moved then stopped at the right end of the screen but when adding the second condition to make it go back everything gone wrong...

Comment: @DarkFalcon and i call it in another function but the code is kinda long so just if i can find a way to post it in formatted way i will do it..

Comment: @Eyad edit you question to add more code in a formatted way

Comment: @Eyad well you are drawing only one frame. You do all the movement in one frame, you never actually draw any positions in-between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about "priority" as you write in one of you comment, it's about control-flow.

What you presumably need to do is make `PooMove` only move by one every time it's called (assuming you call `Go()` over and over again in a loop).

So you want to keep the state of the direction it's going with your `bool iamfree = true; bool iamfree2 = false;` variables, so add them as state of your `Game` class. While we're at it, let's make it just one bool and rename it

```
class Game
{
    bool goingRight;
 //...
};
```

Now you can access that state inside the function and change it there and have it persist between calls.

```
void Game::PooMove()
{
    if (goingRight)
    {
        poox[1]++;

        if (poox[1] + 24 > 799)
        {
            goingRight = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        poox[1]--;
        if (poox[1] < 1)
        {
            goingRight = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's going back and forth, but you can stop it, by introducing another boolean, but I'm going to leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: ok thanks alot it does work now however... when it reduce or increase the x it goes up and down so that require changing the condition to (poox[1] + 24 > 599) as the height value end and it works as it was supposed to be but instead of right and left it goes up and down....i totally don't have a problem with that and i will deal with it like that but i want to know why it inverted the co-ordination .. curiosity you know.. :)

Comment: @Eyad I have no clue how your `Drawpoo` works and how it uses the coordinates. I also don't know how `poox` and `pooy` are declared and allocated

Comment: @Eyad no clue how that would happen with the code you posted

Comment: @Eyad you must have typed `pooy` somewhere instead of `poox` or swapped x and y parameters somewhere

Comment: maybe i will check that....anyway i really appreciate the help from you and everyone and i will post if i did a mistype or not....

Comment: thats strange but i should tell about this.... that happen cause when i initialized the condition with index [1] although i spawned 1 poo only it didn't crash...it just inverted the coordination but when i initialized (wrote the condition ) for index [0] it worked as it should....

Comment: more clarification 
(#define NPOO 1)
instead of  (#define NPOO 3)

Comment: @Eyad `poox` and `pooy` were next to each other in memory, so when you went past the end of `poox` you landed in `pooy`. Btw. that just happened to be the case, you can't rely on this behavior to be consistent across all compilers

Answer (score 0):

If release build break things **you probably have undefined behavior ( may be a race condition)**. And the error is not in the code you provided.

Comment: ....if you mean by break don't work...thats not the case it does open and it don't give an error it just don't behave as it should be 
and about "undefined behavior ( may be a race condition)" i don't know what that means....sorry about that iam beginner but anyway i appreciate that you replied and hope that you explain it more

Comment: @Eyad: By "break", he means it doesn't do what you expect. When code does what you expect under some circumstances, but doesn't do what you expect in other circumstances, it is often the case that your code has [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and any expectations you have for what the behavior of that code should be are unwarranted.

Comment: oh that explains alot...thanks :) and that what happens but it seems to work now after the people effort to help me now

Answer (score 0):

The effect of your `PooMove` function is to move your objects to the right side of the screen, and then back to the left. However, there is no code within the `PooMove` function to view the positions of the objects. So there is no way to actually see the objects moving. The drawing code doesn't happen until after `PooMove` has done its work. Which means you will only ever see your objects on the left side of the screen, because that's where `PooMove` places them.

In fact, as it is now, `PooMove` may as well be written like this:

```
void Game::PooMove()
{
    poox[1] = 0;
}
```

The effect will be exactly the same, only without the time wasted moving the object right then left.

Comment: okie then i have made my tests and reached that result too.... now how to make a priority to functions so that it composeframe then do the poomove() frame by frame